# Solana allowing other wallet to mint or transfer token from my wallet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solana, solana-web3js

How do I make other wallet able to mint or transfer token from my wallet if my wallet's keypair is provided, but I want the network fee to be paid by the other's wallet not my wallet?

Is this possible in Solana web3js?

Answer (score 0):

In the @solana/spl-token sdk. You can use the createApproveInstruction to allow another account to transfer/burn the amount of tokens you have approved.

See this: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#createApproveInstruction